# PayPal DPRP is Disabled for This Merchant

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to create recurring profile using Direct Payment Method.

I have enabled Business Pro account in sandbox accounts like as shown below.

[image: Business Pro Account]

And here are the API Credentials.

[image: API Credentials]

And below is my source code that I am using to create a Recurring Profile.

```
$data = array(
    'USER' => urlencode('tahir.jumpstart-facilitator_api1.nxvt.com'),
    'PWD' => urlencode('BHVM3E9XSLAJP9PX'),
    'SIGNATURE' => urlencode('AAYoJuE-6E-mj5oERynM8zN4s4OrAvfUS7h9g45hGPQmxWb5RJxdJEBp'),
    'VERSION' => '69.0',
    'METHOD' => urlencode('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile'),
    'PROFILESTARTDATE' => gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
    'DESC' => urlencode('RacquetClubMembership'),
    'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Month', 
    'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => 1, 
    'AMT' => 10, 
    'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' => 3,
    'ACCT' => '4032030239913727', 
    'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'VISA', 
    'CVV2' => '123', 
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'James',
    'LASTNAME' => 'Smith',
    'STREET' => 'FirstStreet',
    'CITY' => 'SanJose',
    'STATE' => 'CA',
    'ZIP' => '95131',
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US', 
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'EXPDATE' => '072021'
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($data);
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
die;
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

But when I run above code it shows me below error message.

> TIMESTAMP=2016%2d06%2d09T13%3a52%3a39Z&CORRELATIONID=77466c4ec86e5&ACK=Failure&VERSION=69%2e0&BUILD=22204133&L_ERRORCODE0=11586&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=DPRP is disabled&L_LONGMESSAGE0=DPRP is disabled for this merchant&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

I have searched all over the internet and only thing that they suggest is to enable Business Pro account that is already enabled and you can clearly see this in above screenshot.

I am now lost, would really appreciate if someone can tell me if there is some issue with above code or I am missing something?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please submit a PayPal MTS [ticket](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/) to help you grant the DPRP access.

Comment: I just logged in support account, but it doesn't show any option to create a ticket. Can you please guide me?